# Can not parse String with Simple Date format

Tags: java, parsing, simpledateformat

I have a SimpleDateFormat like this :

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and trying to parse such `2012-Jul-29 17:14:39` 
but I`m getting

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-Jul-29 17:14:39"    at
>   java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sysplan.visixd.blastgauge.BGParser.main(Parser.java:396)

Any idea why ?

Comment: try `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you share the complete code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a **locale** problem, I tried this without any error

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2012-Jul-29 17:14:39");
```

However this failed:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.TAIWAN)
        .parse("2012-Jul-29 17:14:39");
```

So it appears to be a locale problem, you need to specify your locale to `ENGLISH`

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
        .parse("2012-Jul-29 17:14:39");
```

That is:

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: Why can't it be an automatic locale?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky The automatic one depends on the user's environment and is not necessarily `Locale.ENGLISH`.

Comment: Why are you assuming that it needs to be ENGLISH?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Which thing needs to be ENGLISH?

Comment: You said ~"is not necessarily Locale.ENGLISH", which presumes that you want it to be ENGLISH.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Of course you can use any other locale that works. `ENGLISH` is just most likely to work.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Mine(Taiwan) and obviously OP's.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formateadorFechaMedia = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
System.out.println(formateadorFechaMedia.format(now.getTime()));

}
}
```